# How to run commands on a batch file from command prompt?

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd, command-prompt

I was working around creating an batch file to run commands on another batch file. for example: we want to run `md C:\abc` from a batch file. how can I do this?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `call` the other batch file within a batch file:

```
call other_batch_file.bat
```

Comment: didn't work. I have a batch file that accepts commands. and I wanna run the command without openning the original batch file. this is what I wanna do: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat cl C:\Users\Hossein\Desktop\SampleFile.c` . Running the Command With the Argument from a batch file in my desktop.

Comment: What does *accepts commands* and *without opening the original batch file* mean? Did you try `call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat" cl C:\Users\Hossein\Desktop\SampleFile.c`? (Note the quotes).